# Centering a image within a frame - without javascript

Tags: html, css

I wanna center this image in the center of the frame see picture below:

[image]

I use overflow hidden so you cant see the things on the outside of the frame
I need this to be done with only css - no scripts at all, cause its used in 3rd party software that doesn't allow scripts.
Besides this i need to be able to size the image so it needs to be stated as a image tag 
See the fiddle for the elements it must contain. Last but not least it must be css 2.1 at the max so (no css3)!

[Here is a fiddle on the frame](http://jsfiddle.net/QxygK/)

And the HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://preview.fonqi.com/img/explain2.jpg" width="200" />
</div>
```

The css:

```
.frame{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border:2px solid black;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.frame img { margin-top: -50%; }
```

Moves the image up by half it's length.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/QxygK/1/)

You can also use positioning....

```
.frame img { position: relative; top: -50%; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/QxygK/4/)

Answer (score 0):

try the below

Add this line in CSS `img{ margin: -100px 0px;}` it will work

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QxygK/13/

Comment: Shall i know Who and why it is down voted....?.. Have the down voted person tried this....?

Comment: I would venture to bet that it was down voted because using PX for your units limits the user to a specific image size.  Your solution is mostly correct.  Problem is you should have said margin-top: -100px; or margin: -100px 0 0 0;  Your solution applies -100px margin to top and bottom, when it only needs to be on the top.  Then you should have used % to make it more dynamic.

Comment: @Michael : In his query he gave size of frame as 200px... So only i just give the answer in pixel...it's ok..